# Mysql Crash SIGSEGV signal 11, recovered after killing apport

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, crash

My mysql instance (ver 5.6.33) on AWS ( r3.4xlarge CPU Cores : 16 , RAM : 120 GB
, filesystem : XFS ) is crashing with signal 11 .
The instance is EBS optimised with EBS for storage.

At around 9:04 IST, the apport began writing the crash report. It did not finish till 9:29 where we killed apport ( kill -9 46697) and mysql respawned on its own.

PFA the top when we were about to kill apport.
[image]

PFA cpu and available memory graphs, also active number of connections.
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Additional Info**

```
#uname -a
Linux 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 20:42:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Crash dump in /var/crash/

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
Date: Mon Nov 21 09:04:26 2016
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 14.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/sbin/mysqld
ExecutableTimestamp: 1474318064
ProcCmdline: /usr/sbin/mysqld
ProcCwd: /var/lib/mysql
ProcEnviron:
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 TERM=linux
ProcMaps:
.... --- 

ProcStatus:
Name:  mysqld
State: D (disk sleep)
Tgid:  1591
Ngid:  0
Pid:   1591
PPid:  1
TracerPid:     0
Uid:   109     109     109     109
Gid:   116     116     116     116
FDSize:        16384
Groups:        116
VmPeak:        104777096 kB
VmSize:        104214224 kB
VmLck:        0 kB
VmPin:        0 kB
VmHWM: 98602088 kB
VmRSS: 98469508 kB
VmData:        104160476 kB
VmStk:      136 kB
VmExe:    14068 kB
VmLib:     4564 kB
VmPTE:   197320 kB
VmSwap:               0 kB
Threads:       3363
SigQ:  7/983541
SigPnd:        0000000000000000
ShdPnd:        0000000000000000
SigBlk:        0000000000087007
SigIgn:        0000000000001000
SigCgt:        00000001800062e9
CapInh:        0000000000000000
CapPrm:        0000000000000000
CapEff:        0000000000000000
CapBnd:        0000001fffffffff
Seccomp:       0
Cpus_allowed:  ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff,ffffffff
Cpus_allowed_list:     0-127
Mems_allowed:  00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:     0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:       4249548
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    168757
Signal: 11
Uname: Linux 3.13.0-92-generic x86_64
```

Mysql ERROR log didn't have any crash report ( NO LOGS on 9:04 )

```
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] Failed to execute mysql_file_stat on file '/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.006775'
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-11-21 09:29:51 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 60.0G
2016-11-21 09:29:53 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-11-21 09:29:54 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-11-21 09:29:54 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 22930589928913
2016-11-21 09:29:54 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-11-21 09:29:54 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-11-21 09:29:54 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-11-21 09:29:56 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
2016-11-21 09:29:56 47911 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930595171328
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930600414208
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930605657088
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930610899968
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930616142848
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930621385728
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930626628608
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930631871488
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930637114368
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930642357248
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930647600128
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930652843008
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930658085888
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930663328768
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930668571648
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930673814528
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930679057408
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930684300288
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930689543168
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930694786048
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930700028928
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930705271808
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930710514688
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930715757568
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930721000448
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930726243328
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930731486208
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930736729088
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930741971968
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930747214848
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930752457728
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930757700608
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930762943488
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 22930763892518
InnoDB: Transaction 48125747425 was in the XA prepared state.
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 0 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 48125747712
2016-11-21 09:30:02 47911 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2
```

SYSLOG at that time

```
    Nov 21 09:05:01 localhost CRON[46747]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
    Nov 21 09:15:01 localhost CRON[47316]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
    Nov 21 09:17:01 localhost CRON[47334]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
    Nov 21 09:19:37 localhost dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 10.0.42.189 on eth0 to 10.0.40.1 port 67 (xid=0x2441a7cd)
    Nov 21 09:19:37 localhost dhclient: DHCPACK of 10.0.42.189 from 10.0.40.1
    Nov 21 09:19:37 localhost dhclient: bound to 10.0.42.189 -- renewal in 1592 seconds.
    Nov 21 09:25:01 localhost CRON[47648]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
    Nov 21 09:29:50 localhost kernel: [2888896.849170] init: mysql main process (1591) killed by SEGV signal
    Nov 21 09:29:50 localhost kernel: [2888896.849184] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
    Nov 21 09:29:50 localhost kernel: [2888896.886594] audit_printk_skb: 18 callbacks suppressed
    Nov 21 09:29:50 localhost kernel: [2888896.886598] type=1400 audit(1479700790.336:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=47900 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Nov 21 09:30:12 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[48231]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
    Nov 21 09:30:12 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[48235]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
    Nov 21 09:30:12 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[48235]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
    Nov 21 09:30:12 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[48235]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
    Nov 21 09:30:12 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[48235]: Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
    Nov 21 09:30:12 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[48235]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
    Nov 21 09:30:12 localhost /etc/mysql/debian-start[48245]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
```

my.cnf file

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
server-id   = 42189
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

max-connect-errors = 100000

key_buffer_size     = 30M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

query_cache_type        = 2
query_cache_limit   = 2M
query_cache_size        = 64M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

slow_query_log_file  = '/var/log/mysql/slow.log'
slow_query_log       = 1
log_output           = 'FILE'
long_query_time      = 2

expire_logs_days    = 7
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_format       = mixed
log-bin         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
log_slave_updates       = 1

innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1

sql_mode            = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 60G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 20
innodb_log_file_size        = 500M
innodb_log_buffer_size      = 50M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 2

innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown     = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup      = 1

relay_log_recovery=1
relay_log_info_repository=TABLE

max_connections         = 8000
max_heap_table_size     = 64M
tmp_table_size          = 64M
sort_buffer_size        = 256K
join_buffer_size        = 512K

table_open_cache        = 4000

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer_size     = 30M

[mysqld_safe]
syslog
```

Update :
See comments by Michael ( https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11651/michael-sqlbot ) in the question. We shut down apport and although we did not find a solution of SIGSEGV , apport did not make things worse.

Comment: Please review the MySQL error log.  That is going to more relevant than anything shown here so far.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot added mysql error log. Normally mysql records SIGSEGV but here it wasn't able to do so. It logs all the stuff after respawning after 9:24

Comment: I only know enough about apport to know that I don't like it... but I will speculate -- blindly and with no justification whatsoever -- that apport may be the reason you didn't get a proper MySQL crash dump, because it was killed while MySQL was still "in the middle of" crashing (because apport held up the process, doing whatever it was doing).  I could be way off base but MySQL doesn't need apport's help, here.  My instinct says make that utility go away so that if this recurs you aren't left holding a relatively useless bag after several wasted minutes.

Comment: Note also: I would (after taking a complete mysqldump) gracefully stop and restart MySQL once more and address any and all warnings.  And what's going on with `/etc/mysql/debian-start`? I never let the package manager touch my MySQL (oh, you want to magically update my database installation? what could possibly go wrong?) so that's unfamiliar to me, but those log entries leave me feeling queasy about what the Linux distro is trying to do, to be "helpful" ... though this is likely completely unrelated to your immediate issue.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : You are right about the apport part. The wiki link  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport )  is really good and says ( i quote) "Data collection from apport takes a nontrivial amount of CPU and I/O resources, which slow down the computer and don't allow you to restart the crashed program for several seconds" . We have shut down apport. Hopefully will be able to collect more data about crash if it happens again.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : can you advise on how to figure out why SIGSEGV might have occurred in mysql?

Comment: Yes... but we'll need the MySQL stack trace :/ so I'm afraid you'll need to wait for it to happen again.  The stack trace will usually give a pretty good idea of what went wrong or where to start looking.  This should not be related to a problem with your configuration.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Thanks! . Verified that we are better off apport. Sadly can't tick your comment as helpful answer. So updating my answer

Comment: Have you experienced the error again?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot : Yes. Not on this instance but a slave and also not due to seg fault. The stopped instance quickly re-spawned and we even got a log ( unhelpful but I can share it ) in error.log that there was a crash and its restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "load average" of 3000 says says

- `max_connections` is set unreasonably high, and
- the clients are asking for too many connections, and
- there are sloooow queries

So...

- Decrease max_connections to, say, 1000.  Meanwhile provide `my.cnf`; there may be other things that are set unreasonably.
- Explain what your clients are like.  For example, 100 Apache clients with MaxClients=100 would threaten to make 10,000 connections -- which is *not* sustainable.
- Set `long_query_time=1`, turn on the slowlog, wait a day, run `pt-query-digest` on the slowlog, and let's see the 'worst' queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It may be something as simple as adding selected *composite* index(es) to table(s).
- How much data do you have?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It sounds like that could be increased, but it may not need to be.

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 60G, so this is must not be a huge problem. agree with max_connections, plus good to check timeout, if it default it could be thousands connections in sleep state

Comment: Load average implies that thousands are awake.

Comment: not fact - if I correct understand this graph, it not MySQL connection, so the question - what is it - OS connection (Apache?) so with 8000 max connections + 28000 sec default timeout all other 5000 easy could be in sleep (but still from MySQL point of view active) state. It is not for discussion - just moment which also not bad to check

Comment: @RickJames : max_connections is not a problem . We increased it since a lot of apps keep connections open ( and sleep ) . Slow queries aren't there and I am sure did not cause Segmentation fault.

Comment: Can you explain the high Load Average?

Comment: @RickJames : 3K in graph is number of connections. I did not understand about high load average. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: The screen image shows "... Load average 3362.97 ...".  A Load average of 1.0 means (roughly) the process(es) currently running need an average of 1.0 CPUs.  10 is a big number; 50 is big and 'bad'.  3362.97 is really bad.  And it is hard for MySQL to cause such a large number.